# Are there other ways to say "from when I was younger" or "from my childhood"?

Tags: phrasing

For example:

> I loved the cartoons **from when I was younger**
>
> I loved the cartoons **from my childhood**

I was wondering if there were other possible variations of saying this.

Any colorful new words? Or rearrangements?

Comment: When did you stop loving them ?

Comment: I NEVER STOPPED, it was just an example lol

Answer (score 2):

***...of my youth.***

***...of my childhood.***